# Члены или участники?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее: "страны, члены Таможенного Союза" или "участники"? Можно ли вообще быть участником союза (я встречал такое написание в сети). Я понимаю, что лучше всего написать "страны, входящие в ТС", но СЕО-тексты предъявляют свои требования.
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, лучше "страны - члены Таможенного Союза", это общепринято, участники - не ошибка как синоним "участники договора о Союзе ", но точнее члены.